# NodeJS - Q - How to pass a promise in another promise

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I want to return or pass a promise to another promise but i don't know how to do that.
my codes:

```
function seedUsers(){
    var def = Q.defer();

    _seedUsersInDb(function(err, users){
        if(err){
            return def.reject(err);
        }
        def.resolve(users);
    })

    return def.promise;
}

function seedDb(){
    var def = Q.defer();

    _checkCountOfUsers(function(count){
        if(count > 0){
            // already seeded
            return def.resolve();
        } else{
            // we have to use seedUsers() 
            // ????????????????????
            // how to pass seedUsers() ????
            // ????????????????????
        }
    })

    return def.promise;
}
```

What codes do I put in the specified section?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mixing promisified and unpromisified functions is messy, therefore promisify *both* the low level functions :

```
// promisify _seedUsersInDb()
function _seedUsersInDbAsync() {
    var def = Q.defer();
    _seedUsersInDb(function(err, users) {
        if(err) def.reject(err);
        else def.resolve(users);
    });
    return def.promise;
}

// promisify _checkCountOfUsers()
function _checkCountOfUsersAsync() {
    var def = Q.defer();
    _checkCountOfUsers(function(err, count) {
        if(err) def.reject(err);
        else def.resolve(count);
    });
    return def.promise;
}
```

Now, nodebacks completely disappear from your higher level code, in favour of promise chains.

```
function seedDb() {
    return _checkCountOfUsersAsync.then((count) => {
        return (count > 0) ? count : _seedUsersInDbAsync().then((users) => users.length);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to just pass it along:

```
if(count > 0){
    // already seeded
    def.resolve();
} else{
    def.resolve(seedUsers());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do `def.resolve(seedUsers())` - `resolve` does recursively resolve promises.

However, it's much better style to write

```
function seedDb(){
    var def = Q.defer();

    _checkCountOfUsers(def.resolve);

    return def.promise.then(function(count){
        if (count == 0) {
            return seedUsers();
        }
    });
}
```

Don't put anything but `resolve`/`reject` calls in the `_checkCountOfUsers` callback function. Really nothing else.

Or just use [Q's builtin promisification](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks):

```
var checkCountOfUsers = Q.nfbind(_checkCountOfUsers), // assuming it actually uses nodebacks
    seedUsers = Q.nfbind(_seedUsersInDb);

function seedDb() {
    return checkCountOfUsers().then(function(count){
        if (count == 0) {
            return seedUsers();
        }
    });
}
```